# First payment gateway?

Tags: php, security, payment-gateway

I'm recently started a project where the client requested I add a payment gateway to it.  My first thought was fear, I've always avoided working with cash (because I've never trusted my code that much, and don't pretend I know enough about security), but the more I thought about it, the more I realized it *shouldn't* be that hard to implement.

So my question is: How hard is it to implement this?  Should I hire an outside party to look over my code, etc.  What steps should I take to make sure the gateway doesn't get attacked?

Comment: Although this question was closed, I think it is a good question, it probably should just be posted somewhere else. Try asking this on Programmers or Webmasters.

Comment: Yes, maybe http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible use PayPal.  They have extensive documentation and it is relatively simple to implement. As an added benefit you are able to rely on them for payment security. And they have a very good reputation. I have only ever used paypabut there are other systems similar if you can't for some reason.

Comment: That is the plan, my main worry is with people gaming the system to get more for less.  Missing a logic bomb in my code with out a gateway is bad, with one could destroy a bussiness

Comment: Redundancy is your friend. Also, paypal has a Sandbox API that you can use to test your code before opening it to the public. The best advice I was ever given was to over code verifications. "It doesn't matter if this line of code never runs. If it DOES run...you know you did something wrong...but it will still save you some effort." So, never assume that things will go as planned, break things down into the minuscule parts and check check check. It's only scary the first time. Have faith in your code, and test, use the available sandbox API, and you'll do fine.